# Rendering Image in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

Recently I started developing with Libgdx and I have encountered a problem which I can seem to resolve. I want to render an Image object from Scene2d to the screen but it doesn't render anything. It's just shows a blank screen.

Here is my skin.json file:

```
 {

com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image: {
    logo: { drawable: logo }
    exit: { drawable: exit }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
    green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
    white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
    red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
    black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 },
},

}
```

Here is my skin.atlas file:

```
skin.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
logo
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1
  size: 384, 93
  orig: 384, 93
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
help
  rotate: false
  xy: 387, 30
  size: 65, 64
  orig: 65, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
musicoff
  rotate: false
  xy: 454, 30
  size: 65, 64
  orig: 65, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
musicon
  rotate: false
  xy: 521, 30
  size: 65, 64
  orig: 65, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
exit
  rotate: false
  xy: 588, 30
  size: 64, 64
  orig: 64, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
settings
  rotate: false
  xy: 654, 30
  size: 64, 64
  orig: 64, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

ScreenWrapper class:

```
package screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;

import engine.Values;

import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;

public abstract class ScreenWrapper extends Stage implements Screen{

    protected ScreenManager manager;
    public ScreenWrapper(ScreenManager manager) {
        super( new StretchViewport(Values.WIDTH, Values.HEIGHT, new OrthographicCamera()));
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    // All the actors will be added here
    public abstract void initiate();
    public abstract void buildStage();
    @Override
    public void show() {

    }
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        act();
        draw();
    }
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        setViewport(new StretchViewport(Values.WIDTH, Values.HEIGHT));
    }
    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }
    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }
}
```

and here is my main file:

```
package screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;

import engine.Values;

public class MenuScreen extends ScreenWrapper{

    private ScreenRenderer renderer;
    public MenuScreen(ScreenManager manager) {
        super(manager);
        renderer = new ScreenRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public void initiate() {
        manager.getLoader().load("skin.json", Skin.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void buildStage() {
        Skin skin = manager.getLoader().getAsset("skin.json", Skin.class);
        Image logo = new Image(skin.getDrawable("logo"));
        logo.setSize(Values.LOGO_WIDTH, Values.LOGO_HEIGHT);
        logo.setOrigin(logo.getX() + Values.LOGO_WIDTH / 2, logo.getY()
                + Values.LOGO_HEIGHT / 2);
        logo.setPosition(Values.WIDTH / 2 - Values.LOGO_WIDTH / 2,
                Values.HEIGHT);
        addActor(logo);
        Gdx.app.log("X and Y", "X : " + logo.getX() + ", Y : "+logo.getY());
        Gdx.app.log("Width and Height", "Width : " + logo.getWidth() + ", Height : " + Values.HEIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        super.render(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(242/255f, 242/255f, 242/255f, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Ok I narrowed down the problem to my JSON file. It looks like I'm not declaring the logo element correctly. How do I declare Image elements in JSON?

EDIT 2: I tried changing the JSON file to this:

```
{

com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton$ImageButtonStyle: {
    logo: { imageUp: logo, imageDown: logo }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
    green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
    white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
    red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
    black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 },
},

}
```

But it still doesn't work...

EDIT 3: I tried to load just the .png file of the logo into the logo actor as a Texture object but it still doesn't draw anything. I did it like this: pastebin.com/n6iB2ymD

SOLUTION: Ok I finally figured this out. It turns out Values.Logo_Width and Values.Logo_Height were 0 so the size of the Image was set to be 0...

Comment: Please show the ScreenWrapper class. Does it already call `act` and `draw` on the stage?

Comment: I added the ScreenWrapper class

Answer (score 0):

Is `MenuScreen` a `Stage`? It's not so clear from the code. If yes, you need to add calls to the `act` and `draw` methods in the `render` method:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    super.render(delta);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(242/255f, 242/255f, 242/255f, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    act();
    draw();
}
```

These methods draw the `Actors` added to the stage.

Comment: It doesn't work... maybe it has something to do with the json file? Do I declare the logo element in the JSON file properly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you clear the screen before drawing, not after.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(242/255f, 242/255f, 242/255f, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    super.render(delta);
}
```

Also, you are setting a new viewport on your stage without ever updating it, so the viewport doesn't know the size of the screen. Change your `resize` method in ScreenWrapper like this:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    getViewport().update(width, height);
}
```

Comment: I do call these methods in my ScreenWrapper class. I uploaded the code to this post. It looks like I'm not declaring the logo element correctly. How do I declare Image elements in JSON?

Comment: Images don't need to be declared in JSON. Instantiate your image using a drawable name that matches a region name in your atlas. You already did that correctly. Did you fix the order of calling `glClear` and `super.render()`?

Comment: Your code as shown above won't draw anything because you clear the screen after drawing the stage.

Comment: Yes I fixed it but it is not the problem. It still continues to show me a blank screen. Every time a try to access my skin.atlas file without the json file, it emits an error that says "skin.json not found"

Comment: Still doesn't work. I really think it has something to do with the JSON file. I tried using TextureAtlas instead of Skin and in the Image constructor just write atlas.findRegion("logo") but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If it doesn't draw when you use a method having nothing to do with the JSON file, doesn't that show that the problem is not the JSON file?

Comment: I just tried to load just the .png file of the logo into the logo actor and it still doesn't draw anything. I did it like this: http://pastebin.com/n6iB2ymD I'm losing my mind now...

Comment: Yes I did. Now I just load the .png file of the logo, not the all skin. However, it still doesn't work. What could be the problem?